# How to find C# memory leaks identified by 'Dependent Handle' root objects?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, memory-leaks, event-handling

I am trying to release a large chunk of objects (WPF controls, Devexpress Grids with lots of data, etc) and I find that some of these objects are kept in memory even after multiple GC.Collect() and GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers() calls.

When I go to Diagnostic Tools, enable Heap Profiling and create a snapshot, I find 'Dependent Handle' root nodes in the 'Paths to Root' list.

How can I find the actual event handler responsible for this? As far as I've understood an event handler which is not unregistered is responsible for this. Am I right?

I get something like this in the Paths to Root window:
`EventHandler<EventArgs>    <0x1AC128ECF20> [Dependent Handle, RepeatButton <0x1AC128ECD20>]`
I tried to find more info about it based on this [Analyze .NET Framework memory issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/misc/analyze-dotnet-framework-memory-issues?view=vs-2015), but then I got stuck.
(*I added this from my comment below, I think this adds some useful info to the question*).

What are Dependent Handles exactly? (Documentation is very vague on this matter).

Comment: 1) how do you know you have a memory leak? 2) you can't just go and attempt to free memory via `GC.Collect` if they are legitmately in use e.g. _a control/window/object 3) when a window closes do you unsubscribe from any delegates you might have setup manually?

Comment: Some info on _dependent handles_ -  _[Top secret .NET handles – Part 1 – Dependent handles](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/yizhang/2018/02/08/top-secret-net-handles-part-1-dependent-handles/)_.  Though it's probably _more_ than you need to know.    Also if you are using `grids` with _"lots of data"_ then you would be far better looking into _virtualisation_ mode for WPF controls.  It's not as good as native code (where you can control both visuals and data fetch) but it will reduce the amount of "visuals" as they become `recycled`

Comment: Well, it's data which is not needed anymore (the user closed some forms) and it should be eventually freed. I used the forced GC called for testing, and I see that some objects got stuck through these 'dependent handles'. What I am looking for is a quick way to locate the handles which could be leaking. I am not the original author of the code so I need something other than checking every event and delegate manually.

Comment: We don't use ConditionalWeakTable in our code. 
I get something like this in the Paths to Root window:
`EventHandler<EventArgs>    <0x1AC128ECF20> [Dependent Handle, RepeatButton <0x1AC128ECD20>]`
I tried to find more info about it based on this [Analyze .NET Framework memory issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/misc/analyze-dotnet-framework-memory-issues?view=vs-2015), but then I got stuck.

Comment: Have you tried to uncheck the "Just my code" box? In my case, I saw additional related references, eg. WeakEventTable which suggest that this is wrong direction to search, because these instances have weak references